# Button not showing up when canvas.create_window() is called

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-button

I am messing around a bit with tkinter in python, and i want to add some buttons to my canvas screen. But when i run the script, the button is not showing up on the screen. It's a little complicated, but I am creating buttons from a for-loop, then appending them in a list.

**This is my code:**

```
from tkinter import * 

class Application:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.geometry("1280x720")
        self.window.resizable(False, False)        

        self.initHomeWindow()

        self.window.mainloop()

    def initHomeWindow(self):
        def initButtons():
            self.buttonList = []
            self.button_load = {}
            self.button = {}

            imgInfo = [
                    ['Abs', '105', '425.97', '310'], #1st one is button itself, 2nd one is width of the button, 3rd one is the x-position of the button, 4th one is y-position of the button. 
                    ['Arms', '123', '425.97', '370'],
                    ['Back', '117', '425.97', '430'],
                    ['Calves', '128', '848', '314.5'],
                    ['Delts', '121', '425.97', '490'],
                    ['Glutes', '128', '848', '364.5'],
                    ['Hams', '127', '848', '414.5'],
                    ['Pecs', '112', '425.97', '550'],
                    ['Quads', '128', '848', '464.5'],
                    ['Traps', '126', '425.97', '610']
            ]

            for x in range(len(imgInfo)):
                self.button[str(imgInfo[x][0])] = Button(self.window, width=int(imgInfo[x][1]), height=49)

                self.buttonList.append([self.button[str(imgInfo[x][0])], imgInfo[x][2], imgInfo[x][3]])

        initButtons()

        self.window.overrideredirect(False)
        self.window.geometry("1280x720")

        self.canvas2 = Canvas(self.window, highlightthickness=0, bg="#1b1b1b")
        self.canvas2.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)

        for x in range(len(self.buttonList)):
            self.canvas2.create_window(float(self.buttonList[x][1]), float(self.buttonList[x][2]), window=self.buttonList[x][0])

Application()
```

[image]

When I run the script, the button is not showing up on the screen (see image)

I hope someone can help me with this problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre] — don't just apologize for not having done so.

Comment: Right 1 sec then

Comment: @martineau i hope it works now!

Comment: The code example needs to be _minimal_. For example, if the problem is with adding buttons to a canvas, do we really need any images at all? Won't a button with only text work just as well? Also, is the animation code necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sorry! I'm new to stackoverflow, I'm trying!

Comment: All that's need it something that attempts to put a `Button` into a `Canvas` that fails to do so. The process can be triggered by clicking on some other regular `Button`.

Comment: Okay now it should be minimal! Sorry for my dumbness :(

Comment: I think the problem is that the list isn't found. Because i'm defining the list inside a function. But when I define the list out of the function, the ```append``` doesn't work

Comment: Your new minimal program is perfect, and makes it much easier to understand the problem. However, the picture now isn't at all related to the code in the question.

Comment: Changed that as well :) Thanks for the feedback, i'm learning a lot from this!

Answer (score 1):

Your buttons are underneath the canvas on the z-axis due to the order in which you create the buttons and canvas and the fact that the buttons are a child of the root window rather than the canvas.

It would be best to make the buttons children of the canvas, but you can also use the `lift` method to raise the buttons higher in the stacking order:

```
for x in range(len(self.buttonList)):
    self.buttonList[x][0].lift()
    ...
```

Comment: The ```lift()``` doesn't work for me. How can i make them children of the canvas?

Comment: @Itsjul1an: the first positional parameter when creating a widget is the parent of the widget. So, create the canvas first, and then use `self.canvas2` rather than `self.window` when creating the buttons.